# Error in installing JEDI - please install the dependencies first

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I downloaded JEDIVCL package.... according to its help i have to run install.bat from jcl folder and then run install.bat from jvcl folder. i launched install.bat from jvcl folder but i received this error:

[image]

and if run install.bat from jcl folder receive this error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? if its possible give me steps to install this package.

Comment: The first error is, most probably, JVCL installation complaining about JCL not having been installed.. In his answer, Alexander explains the second, but I have no idea why it happens.. Try to proceed with the manual installation as instructed in 'readme.htm'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second error message is crash of Delphi compiler.

install.bat asks Delphi to compile JCL installer, but... Delphi compiler crashes.

This is definitive sign that there is a problem with your Delphi compiler!

Try to install available all updates. Also, try to open installer project in IDE and compile it from IDE (without command-line compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have problem with your Delphi installation.  If you have just installed Delphi make sure you have run it at least once.

You will need to have the DCC32.EXE command line compiler to install JCL.  If I remember correctly this was not shipped in the Turbo or Trial editions of the product.

The JCL/JVCL look in the registry for the location of your Delphi Installations, some versions of Delphi update the registry on the first launch of the product.

Comment: Also if you just installed Delphi 7, you need to reboot (even if NOT asked to) since the JCL/JVCL installer (at least back in the Delphi 7 days) is looking for system variables/paths thas has just been added and that will only be available at next reboot.